# My sign up only triggers Chrome to suggest a password on my local server -- hosted site does not prompt for password suggestion

Tags: html, laravel, frontend

I have a Laravel based website, and on my local server, when I go to sign up, Chrome suggests a secure password, as intended. My hosted website, which is up to date with my local, cache cleared etc, it does not prompt for a password suggestion, and I cannot figure out why. I've also had a friend test this and he receives the same issue.

[image]

As far as I can tell, everything else looks and behaves the same, and it doesn't seem like there is anything that has not been updated. But I thought maybe there was some random thing I had to change that I don't know about for this to work on a hosted website (either in my site configs or my host settings).

I can't imagine my input html would be problematic, as it works on my local server, but just in case, here it is.

```
<input placeholder="Password" id="password" type="password" name="password" required class="w-full form-input" aria-autocomplete="list">
```

Any ideas?